# Why my compiled class has it's methods local variables renamed?

Tags: java, javac

I have a `Kitchen.jar` file. I need to modify a class inside it. I decompile it with [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/). Then I modify the `Toster.java` file and compile it with:

```
javac -classpath . Toster.java
```

And then I take it back into the `Kitchen.jar` with:

```
jar -uf Kitchen.jar Toster.class
```

All works except for one problem. When I open updated `Kitchen.jar` in [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) I see that local variables inside all methods are renamed to something like `localLongVar`. Why?

The reason I ask is because `Kitchen.jar` refuses to work after the modification. And I suspect it has to be the compilation problem. Maybe I've misused some flags or anything. Not sure. I have no knowledge of Java whatsoever, except for the basic syntax.

My guess is that I compile it with latest 1.7 version and original jar is compiled with older JDK. That may explain failure of operation, but that doesn't explain the renaming of locals.

### EXAMPLE

The random line from the original jar:

```
BigInteger[] result = new BigInteger[bis.length / 2];
```

And the very same line of my class:

```
BigInteger[] arrayOfBigInteger1 = new BigInteger[paramArrayOfBigInteger.length * 2];
```

So its `result` vs `arrayOfBigInteger1`.

Comment: How could the name of a local matter? It's local.

Comment: Names of local variables are not preserved in bytecode...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth but JD sees the proper names when it decompiles the original jar. So they are not preserved after my modification, but they are in the original jar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default javac removes debugging information other than source file and line number. Compile with `javac -g` or `javac -g:vars`.

From the [documentation of javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

> `-g`  Generate all debugging information, including local variables. By default, only line number and source file information is generated.
>
> `-g:none` Do not generate any debugging information.
>
> `-g:{keyword list}` Generate only some kinds of debugging information, specified by a comma separated list of keywords. Valid keywords are:
>
> `source` Source file debugging information
>
> `lines` Line number debugging information
>
> `vars` Local variable debugging information

Answer (score 3):

The names of the variables are not preserved in compiled code. Most obvious to reduce the size of the compiled class. The compiler will replace them by shorter names. Doing this is also good for obfuscating the code so that someone who decompiles the code has problems to understand the logic. The `localLongVar` you see in JD is what the compiler makes of the replaced variable names.

Comment: Thanks @user714965, but JD can read the local names when it decompiles the unmodified `Kitchen.jar`.

Comment: Actually ... it is simply what JD has decided to use, given that it has no way to know what it *should* use.

Comment: @AleksandrMakov - where does it read them from?  They are NOT in the .class file!

Comment: @StephenC I have no idea. But for example, this line is enclosed within the original jar `BigInteger[] result = new BigInteger[bis.length / 2];` and the very same line of my class `BigInteger[] arrayOfBigInteger1 = new BigInteger[paramArrayOfBigInteger.length * 2];` So it's `result` vs `arrayOfBigInteger1`.